# Show crystal report from multiple datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have been having this problem for quite some time. 
I created a stored procedure that returns multiple datatable from the procedure.

```
select name,address from table1,
select office,officeaddress from table2
```

I create a dataset from project explorer.
I add in a datatable. Name it and fill the column with the names of all the values that returns from the procedure like below

```
name,address,office,officeaddress
```

I create a crystal report from project explorer and fill it with the table from database expert.But the crystal report shows no values.

Is it possible to show report like the above scenario? The code for filling the report is given below

```
string s = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(s))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_getConfigurationReport", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cashsafeid", 3));
        conn.Open();
        //SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dsConfiguration = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

        da.Fill(dsConfiguration);

    }
 ReportDocument rDoc = new ReportDocument();
 rDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Report/ConfigurationReport.rpt"));
 rDoc.SetDataSource(dsConfiguration);
 EODReport.ReportSource = rDoc;
```

Comment: can you swap two statements of setting data-source and loading report. please, try to first set the data-source and then lead the report.

Comment: The example i written was a demo one.Since there are so many select statements swapping will be very complex,is there any way we can show the report in the above manner.

Comment: please try to change your code as,ReportDocument rDoc = new ReportDocument();
rDoc.SetDataSource(dsConfiguration );        EODReport.ReportSource=rDoc; rDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Report/ConfigurationReport.rpt"));

Comment: Here my doubt is how can we link the dataset retreived from the procedure to the datatable used in the report.